# javascript não exibe image .gif no Chrome e no IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou utilizando Bootstrap e em um modal simulo o processo de envio de dados para o banco.

Quando o usuário clica em salvar exibe uma mensagem de alerta perguntando se é isso mesmo que o usuário quer fazer. Então, se o usuário clicar em "sim" depois que aparecer a mensagem, exibo um load .gif para simular que estou enviando os dados até obter uma resposta.

O problema acontece nos browser Chrome e IE, onde não aparece a imagem no formato .gif, já no Firefox acontece tudo normalmente.

Segue o código: https://jsfiddle.net/pedroaugustoneto/pcv3gv7g/7/, nesse link funciona perfeitamente, só não no projeto.

Comment: O código do seu projeto é exatamente o mesmo do jsfiddle? Ou esse fornecido é apenas um exemplo?

Comment: Eu peguei apenas a parte do Modal, estou utilizando AdminLTE-master: http://minhateca.com.br/ClaytonFerraz/Iclinical/AdminLTE-master,69152643.zip%28archive%29

Comment: Tem algum erro no console? Not found por exemplo

Comment: Não tem erro. Fiz um teste tentando exibir .gif em uma outra div e a imagem carregou, mais depois que o ajax terminou de executar. No caso eu quero que apareça antes. No firefox tudo ocorre normal.

Comment: Tem alguma forma mais fácil pra simular um loading... ?

Comment: Acredito que esse jeito é o mais fácil. O problema é que esse fiddle aí funciona aqui no Chrome, não tenho como ajudar